# Google VR SDK for Unity view gets rotated if device is tilted on startup

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr

I am using Google VR SDK for Unity v1.60. Every time the app starts up, the camera view gets rotated if the phone is tilted.
I want the camera rotation and positon fixed always. but Somehow on startup it is rotating according to the phone and then getting fixed.

Comment: This reads more like the start of a journey and not a specific question.  What's the issue, specifically?

Comment: I want the camera rotation and positon fixed always. but Somehow on startup it is rotating according to the phone and then getting fixed.

Comment: Isn't the point of VR to be able to look wherever you want too? Which would mean to rotate according to the phone.

Comment: But I want to make it fixed for my app.

Comment: probably should edit your original post to include the issue, your expected result, and what you've tried to address your issue.